# Speed up regex matching?

Tags: regex, algorithm, perl

I'm writing a log parser, that reads the log line-by-line, I have around 100 rules and it works like this:

```
if ($line =~ /blabla (field1) (field2)/) 
{ do something } 
else if ($line =~ /something (field1) (field2) else/)
{ do something }
```

But for a big log file, it could be slow to match one line against so many rules, it would be `O(n)`.

So, is there any suggestion on this problem? Since it's not just plain string and wildcard matching, I don't know if there's any data structure I could use.

Comment: Would you mind giving us some sample of your data? And, another question, is any language allowed here?

Comment: @Rubens hi rubens, what you mean by `any language`? You mean if I can accept another programming language?

Comment: yes, sorry, that was exactly the question: can it be made in any language? just noticed there's a tag referring to perl ^^ Anyway, could you get some two or three lines of data, or just an example with the main separators in the lines?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps a dispatch table could be used?

```
my %handlers = (
   blabla    => \&blabla,
   something => \&something,
);

while (<>) {
   my ($keyword) = $line =~ /^(\S+)/
      or next;

   $handlers{$keyword}
      or next;

   $handlers{$keyword}->($line);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe your optimizations are premature.

Have you tried it with this notional big log file?  Is it actually too slow?  Then, if it actually *is* too slow, use a profiling tool like Devel::NYTProf to find out what exactly is being slow.

Comment: Thank you for addressing the issue of regex and regex object matching. Benchmarking showed using the regex was 37% faster than using the regex object. Have deleted my response. +1 for your Devel::NYTProf suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to redesign your log parser. May be I am wrong but I think you try to match all cases which could occur in log file.

Try to use lexical and syntactic parser. Sorry, I don't know good samples on Perl, but something like [Parse::Yapp](http://search.cpan.org/~fdesar/Parse-Yapp-1.05/lib/Parse/Yapp.pm)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple regex into a single one to speed up the matches by using [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3A%3AAssemble)

Below is from the description of the module

Regexp::Assemble takes an arbitrary number of regular expressions and assembles them into a single regular expression (or RE) that matches all that the individual REs match.

As a result, instead of having a large list of expressions to loop over, a target string only needs to be tested against one expression. This is interesting when you have several thousand patterns to deal with. Serious effort is made to produce the smallest pattern possible.

It is also possible to track the original patterns, so that you can determine which, among the source patterns that form the assembled pattern, was the one that caused the match to occur.